# Can entity framework tell you if a database is available?

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a command that entity framework provides to test if a database is responsive or connected?

Answer (score 1):

The **Entity Framework** opens connections *only when required*, for example to execute a query or to call `SaveChanges`, and then closes the connection when the operation is complete.

You can check the State of an existing `DBContext` like so, to inspect it's current `State` and manually open the connection if it's not open i.e. `State != ConnectionState.Open`.

```
if (context.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    // Explicitly open the connection.
    context.Connection.Open();
}
```

You can also manually Open a Connection like so.

```
// Explicitly open the connection.    
context.Connection.Open();
```

**Sources:**

- MSDN - [Managing Connections and Transactions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- MSDN - [How to: Manage the Connection in a Long-Running Object Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738701%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)